# What is the difference between these two methods of data collection?

Tags: dataset, cross-section, case-control-study, collecting-data

I am trying to measure the effect of a campaign on the knowledge of a certain disease on population X

method 1: measure the same individual’s knowledge two times once before and once after passing through the campaign

method 2: measure two different groups from the same population, one group has passed though the campaign and the other group have not

what is the difference and why is one better than the other?

Comment: There are several issues here, such as: (1) the same individual may have changed knowledge between the tests even without the campaign and (2) the two different groups may have had different starting levels of knowledge before the campaign.